# How to index specific tags in HTML with Xpath and SOLR

Tags: solr

In order to avoid data duplication, I intend to only store a crawled HTML file, but have the parsing of the HTML with Xpath done by a filter or function within SOLR at index time.

The html is itself not indexed but is transformed, into fields that solr will index using Xpath.

I am a total newbie in SOLR but I can imagine that I should be able to do something like:

1. Call the DB index URL
2. Register a filter within SOLR that takes each record and transforms it to a number of fields.

Thanks if you have any info.

Comment: This depends on your desired use case. HTML, like XML, is not a flat data structure. How do you want your HTML represented in a Solr document? What 'fields' are you capturing from the HTML? Also, you mentioned avoiding data duplication, that's something that RELATIONAL databases are better for. Finally, once you've indexed the HTML what do you want to do with it?

Comment: I would want to extract specific xpaths, and save them as a solr document on a per db record basis. What i am trying to avoid is having the same data in DB and SOLR when I could always rebuild the SOLR index based on the HTML record in DB.

Comment: How are you planning to index the content? There are [xpath options available](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html#the-xpathentityprocessor) for the DataImportHandler, otherwise you'll have to use xpath and html parsing in the code that submits the documents to Solr (i.e. pre-process it). I usually recommend preprocessing it yourself, since you'll have far more flexibility that way - but using DIH is a very quick way to get started.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if posting items one after the other to SOLR is a good idea for scalability?